What is Considered a Non-fighter in Each of the 4 Madhabs' Mutamads?
As the title says, what is considered a non-fighter in each of the 4 madhabs? Is it restricted to only woman and children, or is the status extended to other categories like the elderly, monks, and laborers? I understand that there have been a couple posts similar to this, however unlike those posts, I am specifically looking for a comprehensive explanation of what each of the 4 madhabs' mutamads relay regarding this topic.

hanafi
According to the Hanafi school of thought the people who are not part of the Ahl al-Qital - and hence can not be intentionally killed during battle or after capture include:

Children

Women

Permanently insane

Extremely old men

Monks and Priests who practice seclusion from the public

Men who are bedridden because of a permanent debilitating disease

Men whose limbs from opposite sides are amputated, or those whose right hand is amputated, or those whose one side is paralyzed

Blind men


They can however be killed if they fight, give advice, incite others to fight, contribute wealth to the war effort, or are kings\queens whose killing will demoralize the enemy. However children and insane people can not be killed after capture.
Ref: Radd al-Muhtar ala al-Dur al-Mukhtar, Fataawa al-Alamgiriyyah, Badaa'i' as-Sanaa'i'

This answer only includes the Ahnaaf though, likewise, when you say contribute wealth to the war effort, does that include taxes? So for instance, a woman or an elderly man is required by their ruler to pay taxes, and these taxes ends up indirectly contributing to the war effort alongside other expenses, have they now become apart of the Ahl al-Qital?
